# custom dataframe sorting using groupedby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and I have a dataframe table:

```
     I    J   GAI         F
0   660  433  6016  0.000844
1   660  433  6020  0.888889
2   660  434  6016  0.010041
3   661  433  6016  0.021373
```

I want to format this so that to have an output that looks like:

```
660: {433: [[6016,0.000844]], [[6020,0.888889]],
      434: [[6016,0.010041]]}
661: {433: [[6016,0.021373]]}
```

Essentially, the output should be grouped by I and J then write the corresponding GAI/F combinations that go along with it.

I used df.groupedby(['I','J']) and got the following which was close but not quite there:

```
((660, 433),      I    J   GAI         F
0  660  433  6016  0.000844
1  660  433  6020  0.888889)
((660, 434),      I    J   GAI         F
2  660  434  6016  0.010041)
((661, 433),      I    J   GAI         F
3  661  433  6016  0.021373)
```

Does anyone have a quick fix to my issue? I've been hunting all day online with no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a nested `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for d in df.groupby(['I', 'J'], as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict('r'):
    x[d['I']][d['J']].append(list(zip(d['GAI'], d['F'])))
```

If you want, can convert back to dict at the end

```
x = {k: dict(v) for k, v in x.items()}

{660: {433: [[(6016, 0.0008439999999999999), (6020, 0.8888889999999999)]],
       434: [[(6016, 0.010041)]]},
 661: {433: [[(6016, 0.021373)]]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `groupby` and `to_dict`

```
df.groupby('I').apply(lambda x : x.groupby('J')[['GAI','F']].apply(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).to_dict()).to_dict()
Out[461]: 
{660: {433: [[6016.0, 0.0008439999999999999], [6020.0, 0.8888889999999999]],
  434: [[6016.0, 0.010041]]},
 661: {433: [[6016.0, 0.021373]]}}
```